# Laravel 5.2 User table seeder error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I created a users table using migrations, but was unable to seed this table. I get the following error when i run **php artisan db:seed** from the command line

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
      parse error, expecting `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"'
```

My UsersTableSeeder.php seeder has the following lines:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder

{

    public function run()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = 'John Doe';
        $user->email = 'john@gmail.com';
        $user->password = bcrypt('password');        
        $user->save();
    }

}
```

My User.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

How can i fix this? 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

add this to user model and let the user model handle the password bcrypt and  storing. this way it can be solved.

UserTableSeeder

```
public function run()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = 'John Doe';
        $user->email = 'john@gmail.com';
        $user->password = 'password';        
        $user->save();
    }
```

User.php

```
Public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
{ 
    return $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is nothing wrong :)

Could you give us more detail? Or have you ever tried

`composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting directly to the database, as the documentation describes:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this UserTableSeeder

```
public function run()
    {
        User::truncate();
        $pavan = User::create([
            'name' => 'something',
            'email' => 'something@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
            'status' => 1,
            'theme' => 'green',
            'is_delete' => 0
        ]);
}
```

In DatabaseSeeder.php

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        \DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
         $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
        \DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
    }
}
```